# Client Side Reprojected Tiles shown at the wrong place

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

**Description**

I have to use a WMTS-Service in EPSG:31254 and show it on an OpenLayers 5 Map in EPSG:3857.
The WMTS-Service to use is [this one](https://vgis.tirol.gv.at/arcgis/rest/services/Basis/basis_karte/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml).

**My Solution**

I use *proj4* and configure "EPSG:31254" according to [epsg.io/31254](https://epsg.io/31254)

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:31254", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=10.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs");
```

Then i configure OpenLayers to use *proj4* and create an OpenLayers Map in EPSG:3857 (i know, its the default projection) with a default background at a given center and zoom level.

Then i add the TileLayer in EPSG:31254:

- read WMTS Capabilities
- build Options from Capabilities
- build WMTS-Source with Options
- add TileLayer with WMTS-Source

**Problem**

An Image is shown, but it's shown at the wrong place (e.g. the Italian Peninsula should overlap!)

[image: wrong image]

**Source Code**

I created an example showing the problem over at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/pjrxxvk5kj)
What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: The top left corner in the WMTS capabilities is 470000.0 -250000.0 which isn't somewhere north west of Austria as it should be.  I suspect it has the x and y axes swapped, in which you won't be able to use the capabilities and will need to set up your own tile grid with origin [-250000.0,470000.0]

Comment: Thats it, thank you @Mike! Write this as an answer and i will upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL:DR

The proj4 definition of "EPSG:31254" according to [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/31254) is missing "+axis=neu".
Here is why:

### Server Side / WMTS Capabilities

According to the [WMTS Specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts) the Coordinates of the topLeftCorner of the TileMatrix should be as specified by the supportedCRS.

> CRS will be inherited from the supportedCRS parameter of the parent TileMatrixSet. The order of these axes, shall be as specified by the supportedCRS. These are the precise coordinates of the top left corner of top
>   left pixel of the 0,0 tile.

In this case, according to [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/31254) the CRS is cartesian and the WMTS Capabilities are correct (Y X).
In this case (470000.0 -250000.0) is (Y X) or (northing, easting).
The WMTS Capabilities are correct [image: check]

### Client Side / OpenLayers

As it looks, OpenLayers does look at the *supportedCrs* and does *switchOriginXY* in case the axis orientation of the projection is 'ne' (instead of 'en')
OpenLayers is correct [image: check]

Which brings us to...

### Client Side / proj4

OpenLayers uses proj4 under the hood. The given definition for EPSG:31254 according to [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/31254) is

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:31254","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=10.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs");
```

This definition is missing the axis orientation!

### Solution

Add "+axis=neu" and the example works (Demo at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/wyw4vvnlw7))
[image: working demo]

Comment: As with all projections OpenLayers only has the proj4 definition to work with. There's no +axis=neu setting in there which would indicate the axes were swapped, although when I tried adding it nothing changed.

Comment: @Mike you are right +axis=neu was missing in the proj4 definition of EPSG:31254. Adding "+axis=neu" and removing the workaround (manual swapping afterwards) fixed the demo!

Comment: There's also an issue with proj4 and the sandbox editer.  Although the map refreshes as soon as an edit is typed in  proj4 doesn't refresh immediately making it appear the edit had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The top left corner in the WMTS capabilities is 470000.0 -250000.0 which isn't somewhere north west of Austria as it should be. I suspect it has the x and y axes swapped, in which you won't be able to use the capabilities and will need to set up your own tile grid with origin [-250000.0,470000.0]